# Access combobox control in another application

Tags: c++, winapi

I am writing a C++ application that extracts a certain information from another program (I don't have source code to this program). Using Win32 API, I can access all the textboxes. For example, `SendMessage(hWnd, WM_GETTEXT, 1024, (LPARAM)charArray)` gives me the textbox value correctly. However, there is a dropdown from which I need to get the selected text, and I can't get it. I used spy++ to find the actual handle of the control, and tried

```
SendMessage(hWnd, CB_GETCOUNT, 0, 0)
```

as well as

```
SendMessage(hWnd, LB_GETCOUNT, 0, 0)
```

but both return 0.

I used spy++ to inspect the control further. As you can see in the attached image, the class name of the control is `ClaDrop_xxxxx`. This leads me to believe that maybe it's derived from another type of control, but I can't confirm since I don't have source code to that application.

[image: Spy++ showing the handle and class name of control]

Can anyone help me figure out how to access the selected value of this control?

Comment: A combo is made of an edit control and a list control. You must get the edit's handle.

Comment: @ZDF Not to send it `CB_GETCOUNT`.  OP, you need to trace the messages (if any) that the app sends to the control, it looks to be a custom control.

Comment: The correct way is UIAutomation

Comment: That too, if the control will play ball. @DavidHeffernan: how do you find out?

Comment: @PaulSanders Yes.

Comment: @ZDF No worries, we all do it :)

Comment: _"a dropdown from which I need to get the selected text"_ I do not understand. Why are you trying to send `CB_GETCOUNT`? Isn't the selected text the same as the displayed one? In which case `WM_GETTEXT` should work (even for a custom control, if written correctly).

Comment: @ZDF I think that was just by way of example.

Comment: Use `CB_GETCURSEL` to retrieve the index of the currently selected item, followed by `CB_GETLBTEXT` with that index to retrieve the text. See [Combobox Control Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/bumper-combobox-control-reference-messages)

Comment: @ZDF and Ken, I tried CB_GETCURSEL with no results, my point is if the control isn't letting me get the count, it probably won't let me get anything else. WM_GETTEXT won't work with ComboBox or ListBox controls, afaik. Have not yet looked into UIAutomation, but thank for suggestion.

Comment: _"[For a combo box, the text is the content of the edit control (or static-text) portion of the combo box.](https://learn.microsoft.com/ro-ro/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-gettext)"_ Are you sure you're using the right handle?

Comment: It’s a custom control that just happens to look like a combo. There’s no reason to expect it responds to combo control messages.