# Are there any Win32 functions I can use to get the count / itemdata from a CComboBoxEx control?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc, ccombobox

My parent dialog has a `CComboBoxEx` control (which is mapped to a derived class called `CDatesComboBoxEx`).

In one part of the application this dialog displays a popup modal dialog. And, inside the modal dialog, it needs access to information from the dates combo.

What I decided to do (which works fine) is pass the address of my combo in the constructor of the popup dialog. So I can now do things like:

- `m_pComboDates->GetCount()`
- `m_pComboDates->GetItemDataPtr(i)`

I was wondering if there was any way to use native Win32 code here instead?

- We can get access to the parents handle (`GetParent()->GetSafeHWnd()`).
- We know the ID of the control on the parent dialog (`IDC_COMBOBOXEX_OCLM_WEEK_OF_MEETING`).

So is it possible to somehow directly get the count and item data?

---

I know that there are these macros:

- [`ComboBox_GetCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windowsx/nf-windowsx-combobox_getcount)
- [`ComboBox_GetItemData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windowsx/nf-windowsx-combobox_getitemdata)

But:

1. Can these be macros be used with `CComboBoxEx` control? And ...
2. How do we get the `HWND` on the combo given the context I previously described?

---

Actually, I think I missunderstood the purpose of those "macros". I can get the combo handle like this:

```
HWND hDatesCombo = ::GetDlgItem(
    GetParent()->GetSafeHwnd(), IDC_COMBOBOXEX_OCLM_WEEK_OF_MEETING);
```

But, `ComboBox_GetCount` does not return a value. Nor the others. So I am somewhat confused.

---

Based on the answer, this bit is now fine:

```
HWND hDatesCombo = ::GetDlgItem(GetParent()->GetSafeHwnd(), IDC_COMBOBOXEX_OCLM_WEEK_OF_MEETING);
int iNumDates = static_cast<int>(::SendMessage(hDatesCombo, CB_GETCOUNT, 0, 0));
```

And inside my `for` loop I am doing this:

```
LRESULT itemData = ::SendMessage(hDatesCombo, CB_GETITEMDATA, static_cast<WPARAM>(i), 0);
auto* pEntry = static_cast<CChristianLifeMinistryEntry*>((LPVOID)itemData);
```

That is the only way I can find to cast it. If I try `static_cast<LPVOID>` it won't work either.

Comment: `ComboBox_GetCount` returns a value. It's the documentation that's broken. It's simply what you get when you trust .NET developers to generate the native platform API documentation. The documentation for **every single preprocessor macro** is broken to the point of being useless. Thank you very much, Microsoft.

Comment: Try `GetOwner()` instead of `GetParent()`. Also, did you pass the main dialog in the popup dialog's constructor? `CPopupMyDlg dlg(this)` ComboBoxEx is derived from ComboBox, so all functions/messages/macros should work the same. The "purpose" of those macros is just convenience, they simply send the proper message.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou I do pass `this` so that is OK. The issue was trying to call my test code in the popup window constructor rather than the actual right part of the popup window class (ie. `OnInitDialog` needs to have been processed before we can call this code).

Comment: Hmm, this may have to do with the initialization, sequence of events etc etc of the MFC classes. Inside `OnInitDialog()` the window (dialog) as well as its children are already created. I would try calling the WinAPI `::GetParent()` instead of the MFC one. I think this would work, even in `OnInitDialog()`.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou Using the existing code **did** work in `OnInitDialog`. It just failed when I tried in the **constructor**.

Comment: On your last bit: Why are you combining C-style casts with C++ casts? No, you can't use `static_cast` to get from an `LRESULT` to a pointer, but you *can* just use `reinterpret_cast<CChristianLifeMinistryEntry*>(itemData)`. That will, effecively, sort of  use a C-style cast but it's far easier to track down `reinterpret_cast` in your code (should you need to) than to go looking for C-style casts.

Comment: @AdrianMole Thanks. My original code was: `auto* pEntry = static_cast<CChristianLifeMinistryEntry*>(m_pComboDates->GetItemDataPtr(i));`.  So I assumed I could continue to use `static_cast`. But your way works. Thanks. Ironic that the underlaying MFC code uses the C style casts still. Not surprised though.

Comment: @AdrianMole You seen this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26490?view=msvc-160 ? It flags it and offers no alternative.

Comment: @AdrianMole I used `#pragma warning(suppress: 26490)`.

Comment: I'm just stunned and amazed that it warns about using `reinterpret_cast` but *not* about using C-style casts. In both your situation *and* in the example given in your linked document, you would *have* to use one or the other.

Comment: @AdrianMole It does actually flag c style casts and not using braces for arithmetic. A whole can of stuff! I didn’t want to bloat and detract from this question purpose which you answered.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't go looking in MFC source code? All that MFC does is at last accessing Win32 APIs. If you look in MFC source code, you'll see everything you need to call with WIN32.

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson I do understand that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I was wondering if there was any way to use native Win32 code here instead?*

Yes, there is. The `SendMessage` function (and its returned value) is what you need …

Once you have the `HWND` of your combo-box, you can send it the [`CB_GETCOUNT` message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cb-getcount) to ask it how many items it contains:

```cpp
HWND hDatesCombo = ::GetDlgItem(GetParent()->GetSafeHwnd(), IDC_COMBOBOXEX_OCLM_WEEK_OF_MEETING);
LRESULT nItems = ::SendMessage(hDatesCombo, CB_GETCOUNT, 0, 0);
```

And, to get the item data associated with a particular entry, send the [`CB_GETITEMDATA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cb-getitemdata) message, with the (zero-based) index of the item in question as the `wParam` argument:

```cpp
//...
LRESULT *ItemData = new LRESULT[static_cast<size_t>(nItems)];
for (int i = 0; i < nItems; ++i) {
    ItemData[i] = ::SendMessage(hDatesCombo, CB_GETITEMDATA, static_cast<WPARAM>(i), 0);
}
//...
delete[] ItemData; // When you're done with the data list
```

Of course, if your item data are pointers (such as if you have an owner-drawn combo with<sup>1</sup> the `CBS_HASSTRINGS` style), you would need to modify the second code snippet accordingly, adding relevant the `reinterpret_cast` operations where necessary. (Note that both the `LRESULT` and `WPARAM` types are defined as being suitable for storing pointers.)

---

<sup>1</sup> The linked M/S documentation page is a bit fuzzy on whether this applies to owner-drawn combos **with** or **without** the `CBS_HASSTRINGS` style.

Comment: Thank you. **But** does this work with a `CComboBoxEx` control? I tried your `CB_GETCOUNT` code as a started and it returns 0. So I am unsure these macros are compatible with `CComboBoxEx`.

Comment: I saw a similar discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/q/51071401/2287576.

Comment: Assuming you are right, how can we get to the `GetComboBoxCtrl` from where we are in the popup?

Comment: `CComboBoxEx` uses `SetItem` etc.. but it **does** have the mthods I am using.

Comment: Looking at the MFC header/source, I see that the `GetCount()` member for `CComboBoxEx()` is basically just this: `return (int)::SendMessage(m_hWnd, CB_GETCOUNT, 0, 0);`. (Plus an `IsWindow()` check.) So, can't see why my suggested code wouldn't work. [[ CComboBoxEx doesn't override the `GetCount()` member for its base `CComboBox`. ]]

Comment: It was because I was doing my tests in the popup window constructor and not `OnInitDialog`.